# JTable won't span up to JFrame's borders

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I can't make the table span up to the JFrame border. I tried using `setMinimumSize` but it didn't work. What am I missing?

ADDED: I'm not interested in adding JScrollPane to the table (yet). I just want to know exactly how to make GridBagLayout resize a particular component to JFrame's borders.

```
public class Ost extends JFrame{
    OstBridge bridge;
    public Ost() {
        Container cp=this.getContentPane();
        GridBagConstraints c=new GridBagConstraints();
        cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // Add button
        JButton b1=new JButton("Button");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.insets=new Insets(20,0,20,0);
        cp.add(b1,c);

        // Table data
        String[] columns={"Album","Url"};
        Object[][] data={
                {"test1","tes2"}
        };
        // Add Table
        JTable table=new JTable(data,columns);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.weightx=1;
        c.weighty=1;
        c.gridwidth=c.REMAINDER;
        table.setBackground(Color.RED);
        table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        cp.add(table, c);

        // Show All
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(320, 240);
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setVisible(true);


    }
```

This is what I get:

[image: http://fjjf.com.ve/i1.png]

And this is what I would like to get:

[image: http://fjjf.com.ve/i2.png]

Comment: I think you need to use the `fill constraint`. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

In the constraints for the table I should've used `GridBagConstraints.fill`:

```
    // Add Table
    JTable table=new JTable(data,columns);
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.weightx=1;
    c.weighty=1;
    c.gridwidth=c.REMAINDER;

    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // this line solves the problem

    table.setBackground(Color.RED);
    table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    cp.add(table, c);
```

Hope this answer helps someone else who's trying to give firsts steps into java as me! :)